# webdav: a directory per-user

Tags: linux, webdav

I configured a webdav server and it works fine . all my users are directed to the same shared folder /webdav :

```
<Directory /webdav>
    Options Indexes MultiViews  FollowSymlinks
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.password
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

no I want that each user has his own folder and he have access only to that folder . so when he login , he'll be automatically directed to his folder and can't see others' folders . 
I found this but didn't work for me :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webdav/
RewriteRule ^/webdav/(.*?)$ /webdav/user/%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}/$1 [L]
```

help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solve a part of the problem : the user can only see his folder (with his name) but is not automatically directed to that folder

```
<Directory /webdav>
    Options Indexes MultiViews  FollowSymlinks
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.password
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
# Restrict /webdav/* to /webdav/%{REMOTE_USER} access only
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webdav/(?:|README\.x?html?|index\..+)$
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} ^(.+)
RewriteCond %1:/webdav/$1 !^([^:]+):/webdav/\1$
RewriteRule ^/webdav/([^/]+) - [F,L]
```